# Cypher & Neo4j : for loop with Cypher request

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I have a list of words that I want to use as seed labels in Neo4j.

These labels are renewed everyday so I would like to automate my Cypher requests.

Here is the list I have today:

List : `list_of_labels = ['crise sanitaire', 'face crise', 'confinement avril', 'crise coronavirus', 'virus guerre']`

I tried this with variables in my Cypher requests:

`def create_seed_property(tx, i):    j = 0    while j < len(list_of_labels): tx.run(" MATCH (n:ARTICLE  {label: $i}) SET n.seed_label = $j RETURN n ")    j +=1`

And next I did this:

`for i in list_of_labels: session.read_transaction(create_seed_property(i))`

I don't know where I'm wrong.

[ADDENDUM]

I would like to add `seed_label` = 0 for 'crise sanitaire', `seed_label` = 1 for 'face crise' etc. I want to add `seed_label` property for each string in the list_of_labels list. But the list is renewed every day, that's why I try to automate it.

Comment: There are many issues in your code. First of all, your `run()` call is not passing any parameters, so that is probably the immediate problem. But, for much better efficiency, you should probably not even be doing this in a loop in the first place. Also, even if your logic did work, you'd end up writing to each `ARTICLE`'s `seed_label` 5 times even though you'd end up with the final property value always being 4. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to add seed_label = 0 for 'crise sanitaire', seed_label = 1 for 'face crise' etc. I want to add seed_label property for each string in the list_of_labels list.
But the list is renewed everyday, that's why I try to automate it.

Comment: I've added that info to your question as an `ADDENDUM`. You should do that in the future as well for your questions that need clarification, etc.

Comment: Thank you @cybersam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `run()` call is not passing any [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), so that is probably the immediate problem. Also, even if your logic did work, you'd end up writing to each ARTICLE's seed_label 5 times but always end up with the final property value being 4 -- this is wasteful and not what you intended.

In addition, for much better efficiency, you should avoid calling `run()` within a loop (or at least minimize the number of times you call `run()` within that loop). Generally, you should pass the values you want to iterate over to the query as *list* parameters, and the use [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) in your query to process the list values. If the lists are not too long, then you can just pass them to `run()`, and no loop is needed. Or, if the lists would be too long to handle in a single transaction, you can keep a loop but pass reasonably-sized *sub-lists* of values to `run()`.

For your specific use case, you should be able to do everything efficiently with a single `run()` call:

```
tx.run("UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE($ls)-1) AS i MATCH (n:ARTICLE {label: $ls[i]}) SET n.seed_label = i",
       ls=list_of_labels)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices. I tried it and it works very well.